# Why is there no function pointer conversion specifier to the printf() family functions?

Tags: c, function-pointers, portability, void-pointers

Printing a function pointer can be done in a portable way in a Kernel but I am wondering why the userspace printf() family functions never got the functionality?
Is the reason because it can't be done in a portable way in userspace, the functionality isn't needed (aside from debugging), etc?
I feel like the need to have a %p specifier would apply to a function pointer specifier also?

Comment: One simply does not print function pointers.

Comment: @FlorinC. you can read each byte out like a hex dump. But I don't understand why void * has a conversion specifier but a function pointer does not have it's own conversion specifier?

Comment: I don't really see what in the question needs to be more focused, so I am voting to reopen it.

Comment: Honestly, the question has no answer. We can suspect, that no one (majority of standard C implementators) have never deemed necessary to implement a special function pointer conversion specifier, but most importantly, as `printf` is a variadic function, there is no universal portable function pointer type that you could eat with `va_args`. I do not know about the status of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2230.htm . The question can't be clearly answered, as you can't answer for why "is there no" function, it's not specific enough. Just "it" was decided there isn't.

Comment: @KamilCuk I was meaning to ask if there were implementation details making it difficult for it being added. I did not know va_args() did not support function pointers. Seems like one of the implementation details making it a challenge was function pointers might not necessarily point to the function at runtime because the dynamic linker will have to resolve it but maybe I misunderstood. I still don't understand how runtime linking poses a problem.

Comment: `details making it difficult for it being added` I do not think so, no, it is not difficult. `I did not know va_args() did not support function pointers` It does support it. I meant, that there is no common universal function pointer type, like `void*` for pointers. But we can convert any function pointer to any other https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p8 . `how runtime linking poses a problem` I do not understand too. I do not think that is any problem at all. It would be odd. No, function pointers work normally, that's not a problem.

Comment: I mean, you could just ask "why is there no <insert any feature> in C?", and there is no specific answer. It's just not there, you can make up reasons.

Comment: "So why was there no addition of a function pointer specifier?" --> No compelling need for that functionality.  When the size of a function pointer is smaller than the size of the widest integer type, use `printf("0x%jX\n", (uintmax_t) function_pointer);`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica true I can't think of a use for it in userspace (except for debugging). Although, I am relieved that I can implement the functionality in a portable way in kernelspace (useful for kernel panic and linking modules I think). Instead of uintmax_t I will add a conversion specifier to print function pointers specifically because the kernel is written in pure C89.

Comment: If your issue is only for a kernel, add that tag.  If only for C89, add that.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I think casting uintmax_t is implementation defined so it is not portable even if I was using c99. The hexdump is the most portable for both a %p specifier and function pointer specifier for both userspace and kernel.

Comment: @cbot, when `uintmax_t` is sufficiently wide, conversion is well defined: "Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type." C17dr  6.3.2.3 6.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica well I am not sure what my ABI is going to be and for some architectures that might not hold true (PowerPC64 not sure if it is just in page tables that this might not hold true, similar to i386 with PAE enabled). You are right, doing it the way you mentioned is better because it is printed in the same way on all architectures with little effort. Where as using the hexdump you would need a lot more effort to have the output print in a portable way across architectures.

Comment: @cbot, whatever approach, isolate conversion of a function pointer to text in a helper function that can be adjusted as needed.

Comment: _Printing a function pointer can be done in a portable way in a Kernel_  What do you mean with a portable way in a kernel?  How many kernels have you found printf() in and seen how portable are the individual printf functions of all those kernels?  :-)

Comment: @LuisColorado you can implement the function pointer specifier in the kernel in a portable way (you don't need to use assembly or machine specific C code) by using a hexdump of the function pointer. The output of the function pointer specifier will be implementation specific (similar to the %p specifier).

Comment: you can also convert the pointer to the biggest integer supported by the machine and then using that integer formats to do the actual printing.... but this is the first time that I hear that kernel code is more portable than used mode code.

Answer (score 2):

While technically undefined behavior, it's a common extension for C compilers to allow conversion from function pointers to object pointers and back. In fact, it's required by POSIX due to `dlsym`'s function signature.

So if you are debugging, you could `printf("%p\n", (void *)funptr);`. If you are not debugging, take a step back and ask yourself why you need the function's address.

Comment: It is for when kernel panic happens it would be nice to print the function address that was last in the instruction pointer.

Comment: I know it is a compiler extension but I am asking why was there no conversion specifier added? I do not see the issues with adding one to printf()?

Comment: A function pointer may hold more information than just the entry point of a function. See e.g. [function descriptors on PowerPC](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/power/blogs/archive-user/2013/08/01/deeply-understand-64-bit-powerpc-elf-abi-function-descriptors). The standard committee avoided delving into these details by leaving it undefined. You can't write a kernel in standard C anyway, so if you know your compiler's guarantee, just cast them. For example Linux defines `%pB` that symbolizes function pointers.

Comment: @af3 Ohhh ok that almost answers my question! Thank you! But %p is also implementation defined so how is that different from printing a function pointer? Couldn't a void * also hold more information also?

Comment: @cbot Yes, printing a `void *` with `"%p"` is not specified to print all the information contained in a `void *`.  E.g. parity or segmentation info may not get printed.  Printing with `"%p"`  is reasonably expected to allow one to later form an _equivalent_ pointer (though maybe a different bit pattern) using `scanf("%p", ...`.  If you want all info, use a bit dump of the pointer.  Keep in mind: pointers are not integers.

Comment: @a3f I am not sure I fully understand why dynamic linking (such as you mentioned in the PowerPC SysV ABI) causes a problem. Is it because the function pointer would hold the address of the function descriptor and because we are reading the bytes from the pointer and not calling it the linker has not resolved the address therefor you are reading the function descriptor bytes and not the actual resolved function address? Couldn't the linker account for this at initialization time (taking a runtime penalty)?